# creative art-work

Tags: copyright

I have pictures which I've transformed into my own art and have watermarked. I've shared them with one other person. How do I legally prevent not only this person from using, distributing or selling these pictures but anyone for that matter?

Comment: *"I have pictures which I've transformed into my own art "* -- More info is needed. Are these **your** "pictures" or just "pictures' you found and altered?? "transformed" how? In what manner? Merely altering *some one else's photograph* never makes it *your* photograph.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you don't have to do anything. You reserve all rights through copyright automatically.

However, if you want, you can provide the other person, and everyone for that matter, a license to use them. If you choose to do this, I would recommend the [CC BY-NC-ND license from Creative Commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/). This license allows people to share the material, under condition that you must attribute the author, you may not distribute any modified forms of the material, and you are not allowed to use the material for commercial purposes.